# Error Handling with Observable.Using and Observable.Retry

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to combine `Observable.Using` with `Observable.Retry`

I have two kinds of errors that can occur:

1. Fatal errors, that need disposal and subsequent recreation of the underlying `IDisposable`.
2. Transient errors, that do NOT need disposal of the `IDisposable`.

I can use `Retry` to handle the first kind of errors.
But how do I handle transient errors?

Below a toyed-down example that hopefully illustrates the problem.
If possible, the solution should allow me to write the code in the same "railway oriented" manner.
The solution should work for both hot and cold observables.

```
var subscription = Observable
                  .Using(() => new Foo(), foo => foo.Observe())
                  .Select(i => ThrowIf(i, 2))  // fatal error
                  .Retry()                     // Foo should be disposed (works)
                  .Select(i => ThrowIf(i, 5))  // transient error
                  .Retry()                     // Foo should NOT be disposed here   
                  .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

Console.ReadLine();
subscription.Dispose();


class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public Foo()          => Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo) + " created");
    public void Dispose() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo) + " disposed");

    public IObservable<Int32> Observe()
    {
        return Observable
              .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
              .Select(_ => DateTime.Now.Second % 10);
    }
}


Int32 ThrowIf(Int32 i, Int32 n)
{
    if (i == n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!" + i);
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return i;
}
```

Sample output:

```
1
!2
Foo disposed
Foo created
3
4
!5
Foo disposed     <= 
Foo created      <= this should not happen
6
7
```

**Edit, clarify:**

The order of the error sources matters:
*fatal* followed by *transient*.

In the real code the `IDisposable` is a `UdpClient`,
The *fatal* error source is `UdpClient.ReceiveAsync()` and
and *transient* is a function that parses the data received.

Comment: In case of the error 5, where the `Foo` should not be disposed, do you want to resubscribe to the same observable returned by `foo.Observe()` previously, or to invoke the `foo.Observe()` again and acquire a new observable?

Comment: Same observable/subscription on `foo.Observe()`. In the real code the second `Select` depends on the output of the first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible to solve this problem using a single railway. If you are OK with adding a branch, here is a solution:

```
var observable = Observable
    .Using(() => new Foo(), foo => foo.Observe()
        .Select(i => ThrowIf(i, 5))
        .Retry() // Foo should NOT be disposed
    )
    .Select(i => ThrowIf(i, 3))
    .Retry(); // Foo should be disposed
```

The branch inside the `Using` deals with transient errors, and the outer (main) railroad deals with fatal errors.

Comment: ty @Theodor. 
You switched the order of the fatal/transient error sources.
My apologies if I did not make it sufficiently clear that the order matters :|
I made an edit to clarify.

Comment: @3dGrabber I don't think that the order of the errors matters. If an error is fatal, the `Foo` will be disposed and recreated. If it's transient, the existing observable of the existing `Foo` will be re-subscribed. This will happen any number of times and in any order, until a subscription completes without an error.

Comment: @3dGrabber *"the second Select depends on the output of the first"* this is probably a show-stopper for my answer though. You should probably modify the example in your question to reflect this dependency!